# Does Qt have combo boxes like Word?

Tags: qt, combobox

In Microsoft Word, if you want to use Bullets you have a combo box (If we can call it a combo box) to select the shape of the bullet (by clicking the little triangle) or you can just apply the default one by clicking the combo box's button.

[image]

Actually the combo box in Word has two parts. For an example let's consider a situation where I want to have a combo box in Qt that has these items as menu items: 
**"Restart"**, **"Shutdown"** and **"Log off"**. User needs to choose one of them but he also can apply previously selected item by clicking its button **exactly like Windows shutdown menu in start**. You can click **Shut down** or select another option.

[image]

How can we achieve this in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are pursuing after a menu that looks like in the second picture, you can use `QToolButton` to achieve your goal. Use a `QToolButton` with `popupMode` set to `MenuButtonPopup`. It will render a control something similar to following.

[image]

Then you can style the look & feel further more using [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet.html). Read this example on [how to style a QToolButton.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbutton)

Create a `QMenu` dynamically, so you can attach it to the `QToolButton` at run-time in such a way that all items will be included in the menu except for the default item. Default action has to be assigned to the `QToolButton` itself.

You can use void `QToolButton::setMenu (QMenu * menu)` to assign a `QMenu` to your `QToolButton` at run-time.

If you are trying to design a control that is in your 1st screenshot, you will have to create a custom Qt control I guess. There is no default control available, which can yield that look & feel out of the box.

Comment: As a followup, the control the OP is using relies on the Ribbon framework for the popup. Since the Ribbon framework is not cross-platform, Qt doesn't have support for it.